# Use Python to send SMS as a given name

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, sms, sms-gateway

How can I send an SMS email as a name such as `Joe Doe` or `(846) 596-2256`?

I can send an SMS message to a phone number with any email I want with this code here

---

```
import smtplib

to = 'xxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.com'
sender_user = 'xxx@provider.com'
sender_pwd = 'xxx'

fake_email = 'fake@fake.com'
fake_name = 'Fake Name'

message = 'This is a test message!'

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.emailprovider.com", 587)

smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo

smtpserver.login(sender_user, sender_pwd)
header = f'To: {to}\nFrom: "{fake_name}" <{fake_email}>\nSubject: \n'

msg = header + '\n' + message + '\n\n'

smtpserver.sendmail(sender_user, to, msg)

smtpserver.close()
```

---

And it appears on the phone like this

---

[image: Fake Text Message ScreenShot]

---

Is it possible to remove the @domain.com part? If I do not enter a valid email (Containing a `*@*.*`) the text message will either not go through entirely or appear as a text message sent by `6245` which after a bit of research is the number which Verizon (my carrier) will send an invalid SMS as. Can I do this with just a python script?

Comment: if portal doesn't accept mails without `@domain.com` then you can't do this in python and in any other language.

Comment: @furas Sorry, I'm kinda new to this email SMS stuff so can you clarify, is the portal that you are referring to the carrier of the target or the email service I am using to send the email?

Comment: Small suggestion, consider to use f-strings instead of + strings. `f'To: {to}\nFrom: {fake_name} <{fake_email}>\n{Subject}: \n'` it really makes things easier to understand. `msg = f'{header}\n{message}\n\n'`

Comment: @furas Would it be possible to force the messager to display only the `fake_name`. That way I could send it as whatever email as I wanted and allow it to get through but still have control over the final name displayed